# Show that expression is Gamma distribution with given parameters

Tags: statistics, gamma-distribution, log-likelihood

I had the expression $$\frac{1}{p(y)}(n\lambda)^k e^{-n \lambda}$$
for $k \in \{0,1,2,...\}$ where we here have that $k=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$ where I think I can ignore $p(y)$, but if not it is given by $p(y)=\int_0^\infty (n \lambda)^k e^{-n \lambda} \, d\lambda$. And we have that $\bar{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum y_i$. Now I have to show that this is Gamma distribution with
shape $n\bar{y} + 1$ and rate $n$ (scale $\frac{1}{n}$). I have tried many times but can not figure it out how to show it without getting problems. Can anyone help me?

If I calculate backwards I think if I insert the given shape and rate I get:
$$f(\lambda,n \bar{y}+1,n)=\frac{n^{n \bar{y}+1}}{\Gamma(n\bar{y} + 1)}\lambda^{n\bar{y}}e^{-n \lambda}$$
But I can figure out how to rewrite the two expressions in order to show they are the same. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Write down the form of a Gamma density. What are your attempts and problems you face?

Comment: I have wrote down the form of the gamma density. But I can not get further. Hope anyone can help me?

Comment: do you mean you are not given the expression of $p(y)$?

Comment: I just forgot the expression for k, I have edit it now

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$f(\lambda) = \frac{n^k}{p(y)}\lambda^ke^{-n\lambda}$$

is a density function where $\frac{n^k}{p(y)}$ is independent of $\lambda$.

Hence, by comparing with the pdf of [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), we conclude that it is a gamma distribution  with the shape parameter being  $k+1$ and the corresponding rate is $n$.

Note that the shape is equal to

$$k+1 = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i + 1 = n\bar{y} + 1.$$